# Speeding up I/O bound python program

Tags: python, concurrency

I have the following program. I have 90 million domain names split between 87 files. I need to resolve the IP of all. Right now I feel like this is super slow.

```
import multiprocessing
import fileinput
import socket
from datetime import datetime

socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)

def worker(i):
    filename = (str(i).zfill(len(str(111))))
    buffer_array = []
    for line in fileinput.input(f"./data/{filename}"):
        domain = '.'.join( list( reversed( line.split('\t')[1].split('.') ) ) )
        try:
            ip_list = socket.gethostbyname(domain)
            buffer_array.append(ip_list)
            if(len(buffer_array) == 1000):
                with open(f"./parsed_data/{i}", "a+") as save_file:
                    save_file.write("\n".join(buffer_array))
                    buffer_array = []
                    print(f"{datetime.now()} -- WRITING: worker {i}")
                    save_file.close()

        except Exception as e:
            pass

    with open(f"./parsed_data/{i}", "a+") as save_file:
        save_file.write("\n".join(buffer_array))
        print(f"{datetime.now()} -- WRITING ***FINAL***: worker {i}")
        save_file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(87):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

In node, I was able to do 1,000,000 on a 2017 macbook pro in about 12 hours without using workers. Right now this accomplished 39 million in 32 hours. My hope was I could make it do it's thing in 12 hours (1m per worker in in 12 hours) on a AWS T3aXL

Does anyone have a bit faster way of doing this?

Comment: Surely the bottleneck is speed of DNS lookups.

Comment: where is multiprocessing being used?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I forgot it lol.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to do this faster with an async library.

Comment: Generally, use threads or async for I/O bound code such as yours.  See [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) or maybe [asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently).

Comment: @Quesofat Before worrying about async, start as simple as possible: use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html). That alone might be fast enough for you.

Comment: Threading slowed things down quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

### Minor Python cleanup

First, a bunch of little stuff:

This -

```
(str(i).zfill(len(str(111))))
```

does not need outer parens. Also, why the acrobatics to get "3"? Just declare a `MAX_DIGITS = 3`.

This -

```
'.'.join( list( reversed( line.split('\t')[1].split('.') ) ) )
```

should not be creating an inner list. The output of `reversed` is iterable.

This -

```
if(len(buffer_array) == 1000):
```

does not need outer parens; you're not in (C/Java/etc).

This -

```
save_file.close()
```

needs to be deleted both places that it appears. There's an implicit `close()` from your use of a `with`.

This -

```
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

is a bad idea. Log or output the exception.

`87` deserves a named constant.

### Broad performance

`gethostbyname` is probably slow (as indicated in the comments). Consider running a local caching DNS resolution service to eliminate the first network hop.

Comment: I appreciate it. I'm not a Python dev. I'm a node / ruby dev. What's this about local caching DNS resolution? Do you have a link to some literature?

Comment: https://nlnetlabs.nl/projects/unbound/about/